# DefaultHttpResponse errors when content is too large

Tags: scala, netty

I am using netty-3.5.11.Final.jar

My bootstrap looks like:

```
val bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(channelFactory)
bootstrap.getPipeline.addLast("httpDecoder", new HttpRequestDecoder())
bootstrap.getPipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpChunkAggregator(1024 * 1024 * 1024))
bootstrap.getPipeline.addLast("httpEncoder", new HttpResponseEncoder())
bootstrap.getPipeline.addLast("deflater", new HttpContentCompressor())
bootstrap.getPipeline.addLast("handler", new HttpRequestServerHandler())
bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true)
bootstrap.setOption("child.keepAlive", true)
```

My `handlePost()` looks like:

```
def handlePost(context: ChannelHandlerContext, request: HttpRequest) = {
  val response = new DefaultHttpResponse(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpResponseStatus.OK)

  val body: Array[Byte] = ....

  response.setContent(ChannelBuffers.wrappedBuffer(body))
  context.getChannel.write(response)
  context.getChannel.close
}
```

If I try to send a body of length 260000 bytes then it sends correctly.  If I send a larger byte array then I get the following exception:

```
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.cleanUpWriteBuffer(AbstractNioWorker.java:766)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.close(AbstractNioWorker.java:734)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.handleAcceptedSocket(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:111)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink.eventSunk(NioServerSocketPipelineSink.java:66)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.oneone.OneToOneEncoder.handleDownstream(OneToOneEncoder.java:54)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.close(Channels.java:820)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.AbstractChannel.close(AbstractChannel.java:197)
at com.lendingblocks.services.ServiceServer$HttpRequestServerHandler.messageReceived(ServiceServer.scala:65)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentEncoder.messageReceived(HttpContentEncoder.java:81)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpChunkAggregator.messageReceived(HttpChunkAggregator.java:192)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:448)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:538)
at org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:437)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:84)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.processSelectedKeys(AbstractNioWorker.java:471)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:332)
at org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:35)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of netty is async ops.

Write call doesn't block to wait for write completed. Write and close are racing each other who will finish first. You need to register the future listener and close the channel on write completed.